# The web host (Apache) will not display a web page from an IIS server

Tags: asp.net, apache, iframe, https

The iframe is being served by Apache (InMotionHosting) and the requested page is from an IIS Server (WinHost). TLS is enabled on both sites. In the iframe, Firefox says 'wcswanson.net will not allow Firefox to display the page if another site has embedded it.'

The code for the iframe is as follows:

```
<iframe width="99%" height="600px" src="https://wcswanson.net/deig3/" title="Downeast Intergroup Online Meetings"></iframe>
```

On the IIS Server the web.config file has the following code:

```
...<httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="https://wcswanson.net/deig3/" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
```

This does not work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

> Firefox says 'wcswanson.net will not allow Firefox to display the page if another site has embedded it.'

Because the page being linked to includes an `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` HTTP response header that prevents the page being embedded in an IFRAME on another site.

> ```
> <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="https://wcswanson.net/deig3/" />
> ```

This is not a valid value for this response header. (Only `DENY` and `SAMEORIGIN` are supported.)

Try removing the header:

> ```
> <remove name="X-Frame-Options" />
> ```

Comment: Sorry that does not work either. Same results.

Comment: @WCS The `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` header is still being set on the response. This would appear to be set conditionally when the content is embedded.